# Is it safe to copy Linux kernel .config file to a different version?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Particularly is it safe to copy a .config file from a Kernel 3.0.1 to a Kernel 3.2.1?

Comment: This is a great question! However, it's not really programming related, so it it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. But it would be a great fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. But make sure you run `make oldconfig` so that new options are added to it.